# divs inside nowrap wrapper breaking line

Tags: html, css

I have 2 floating div's which I want to be on the same line, together they are over 1024px wide, so they require horizontal window scroll, but despite wrapping them in a div with `white-space:nowrap;` the divs will break and appear on two lines. I'm I dong something wrong in this code? Thanks.

```
.wrapper{
          white-space:nowrap;
        }
.content{
         float:left; width:600px; height:20px;
        }

 <div class = "wrapper">
     <div class = "content" style = "background-color:red;"></div>
     <div class = "content" style = "background-color:blue;"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying fixed width for `.wrapper` fixes your issue

```
.wrapper {
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: 1300px;
}
```

### Update

alternately you could set `display: table-cell` for your `.content` and set a `min-width` for them

```
.content {
  display: table-cell;
   height: 45px;
   min-width: 600px;
   overflow: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve with with an other wrapper:

```
  <html>
      <head>
         <style>
            .wrapper{
                position: relative;
                overflow:hidden;
                height: 20px;
            }
            .nowrap{
                white-space:nowrap; 
                width: auto;
                position: absolute;
                height: 20px;
            }
            .content{
                float:left; width:600px; height:20px;    
            }
         </style>
     </head>
     <body>
         <div class = "wrapper">
             <div class="nowrap">
                 <div class = "content" style = "background-color:red;"></div>
                 <div class = "content" style = "background-color:blue;"></div>
             </div>
         </div>  
     </body>
 </html>
```

In this case you must look after the `height` properties! Use this solution only when you know the height of the elements, for example if you create an image slider or something like that.

notes:

Be careful with the `absolute` position. I used that, because in `absolute` `position`ing the dimensions of the element does not closed inside the parent element. The reason why your two divs broken to two lines was that the container element of `.content` did not have `absolute` position.
An absolute positioned element always should be inside a relative element (this is why i used an other wrapper) So you can repeate the code only together (dosen not put an other `.nowrap` div inside the `.wrapper` `div`.

Comment: You are welcome :) 
notes:
Be careful with the `absolute` position. I used that, because in absolute positioning the dimensions of the element does not closed inside the parent element, and this was the reason why your two diws broken to two lines.
And an absolute positioned elementt always must be inside a relative element (this is why i used an other wrapper) So you can repeate the code, only together (dosen not put an other `.nowrap` div inside the `.wrapper` div.

Comment: I guess you will use javascript/jquery to allow access to the hidden content?

Comment: Yes, this code should scrolled by JS (Like a jquery slider, etc .. ). This solution is good only when this is the situatuion.